# Changing image on hover the text

Tags: javascript, html, css

There are 4 texts. When I hover on each of them I can see a certain picture which belongs to certain text.

The question is that, I need a slider consist of images. I mean when I hover on `text1` I need to see my image and after one second this image has to disappear.

So, I need to do it with all texts, but in my code I just can see one image, apart from it is not a slider. Can you help me in this question?

This is the code:

```css
.pic {
  background-image: url(img/scr-img/1.png);
  width: 236px;
  height: 420px;
  transition: 1s;
  background-size: cover;
}

p1:hover~.pic {
  background-image: url(img/scr-img/8.png);
}

p2:hover~.pic {
  background-image: url(img/scr-img/9.png);
}

p3:hover~.pic {
  background-image: url(img/scr-img/11.png);
}

p4:hover~.pic {
  background-image: url(img/scr-img/5.png);
}
```

```html
<p1 style="cursor: pointer; font-size: 24px; color: #1A264A;">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="download-content sm-center xs-center xs-mb50 xs-font wow fadeIn">
      <p>Text1</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</p1>
<p2 style="cursor: pointer; font-size: 24px; color: #1A264A;">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-md-offset-4 col-lg-offset-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="download-content sm-center xs-center wow fadeIn">
      <p>Text2</p><br><br><br>
    </div>
  </div>
</p2>
<div class="pic" style="border-radius: 20px;"></div>
<p3 style="cursor: pointer; font-size: 24px; color: #1A264A;">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="download-content sm-center xs-center xs-mb50 xs-font wow fadeIn">
      <p>Text3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</p3>
<p4 style="cursor: pointer; font-size: 24px; color: #1A264A;">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-md-offset-4 col-lg-offset-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="download-content sm-center xs-center wow fadeIn">
      <p>Text4</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</p4>
```

Comment: Excuse me but what are `p1` `p2` `p3` `p4`?

Comment: @zmuci these are paragraphs which equal to certain text

Comment: my point is that `p1` .. `p4` are not valid HTML tags. Unless you are using some sort of JS framework and these are custom components.

Answer (score -2):

This would not be like a slider but inside of `pic div` we can change images when `Texts` are hovered.
I assume that we have all the required images in folder `img/src-img` and `img` folder is in the same directory where the html page exists.

Below code is working fine in Chrome

```css
.pic {
  background-image: url(img/scr-img/1.png);
  width: 236px;
  height: 420px;
  transition: 1s;
  background-size: cover;
}

p1:hover~.pic {
  background-image: url(img/scr-img/8.png);
}

p2:hover~.pic {
  background-image: url(img/scr-img/9.png);
}

p3:hover~.pic {
  background-image: url(img/scr-img/11.png);
}

p4:hover~.pic {
  background-image: url(img/scr-img/5.png);
}
```

```html
<p1 style="cursor: pointer; font-size: 24px; color: #1A264A;">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="download-content sm-center xs-center xs-mb50 xs-font wow fadeIn">
      <p>Text1</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</p1>
<p2 style="cursor: pointer; font-size: 24px; color: #1A264A;">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-md-offset-4 col-lg-offset-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="download-content sm-center xs-center wow fadeIn">
      <p>Text2</p><br><br><br>
    </div>
  </div>
</p2>

<p3 style="cursor: pointer; font-size: 24px; color: #1A264A;">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="download-content sm-center xs-center xs-mb50 xs-font wow fadeIn">
      <p>Text3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</p3>
<p4 style="cursor: pointer; font-size: 24px; color: #1A264A;">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-md-offset-4 col-lg-offset-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="download-content sm-center xs-center wow fadeIn">
      <p>Text4</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</p4>
<div class="pic" style="border-radius: 20px;"></div>
```

Comment: so what changes can you offer?

Comment: So what can you say about `p1` , `p2` , `p3` and `p4`

Comment: @timur I just changed the position of pic div because for p1, p2 it was working fine. To get it worked for p3 and p4, pic div should be after p3 and p4 as well. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: @Ramesh, I cannot understand your question. Please elaborate what do exactly you want to ask?

Comment: @Anki I want to create a slider of images. and when I hover on some text I need to see certain image and I need to do it with all texts